# Ramifications of Embedding UITabBarControllers in UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've read a number of SO questions on this subject and the general consensus seems to be that this shouldn't be done. It's also stated that Apple's design guidelines do not recommend this approach.

My question is however, what are the ramifications of doing so. I've tried it and it seems to work ok so why not do it? A lot of the SO posts are quite old now so is the info out of date?

Also, if it is still not recommended, what is the "Apple" way to do this? Is it to add a `UITabBar` to each "tab" and manage the transitions programatically?

Comment: Could you point to an Apple reference not recommending to do so?